# Jupyter Notebook "Notebook changed" keeps appearing

Tags: jupyter-notebook

i keep getting the following message : "The notebook file has changed on disk since the last time we opened or saved it. Do you want to overwrite the file on disk with the version open here, or load the version on disk (reload the page)?" on Jupyter notebook even though i didn't make any changes, how can i fix  this problem?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Here's something to point you toward several possible solutions. Not sure why no one has commented or answered this yet, since from the link below this has been a problem through many versions of jupyter since at least 2015 and continues to be today.

What I gleaned from the issue report below is this seems to be an issue with the volume mount, specifically with a clock difference between the local machine and the server. For leads and some temporary patches, see https://github.com/jupyter/notebook/issues/484.

Answer (score 3):

I had this same problem when the file address of the notebook I was using was really long. The notebook was inside too many folders, making the address too long for the kernel.

I fixed this problem by moving my notebook.ipynb to my desktop to shorten the path as much as possible.

The message "The notebook file has changed on disk since the last time we opened or saved it. Do you want to overwrite the file on disk with the version open here, or load the version on disk (reload the page)?" finally stopped popping up.

Comment: Thanks a lot.  It served to me to just shorten the file name.

Answer (score 1):

I have faced their issue and it was really annoying. By just moving my notebook.ipynb to my desktop, thus shortening the path, it worked. So, the issue seems to be the long path to the notebook.ipynb. Hopefully, some future updates will solve the problem, but for the time being, shortening the path works great.

Answer (score 0):

Simple solution that should work for almost everyone:

Reduce the size of the filename. In other words make it shorter.

For instance:

- "C:\Users\Sky\Desktop\For university\Docs for uni\For
  University\DL\Courses complete\Program ok\1 - Neural Networks and
  Deep Learning\Week 3\**Planar data classification with one hidden
  layer**"

To

- C:\Users\Sky\Desktop\For university\Docs for uni\For
  University\DL\Courses complete\Program ok\1 - Neural Networks and
  Deep Learning\Week 3\**OneLayerNN**'

This should fix it!

If it's still not short enough, try to move the folder somewhere where its path is shorter, say for instance, the desktop

Answer (score 0):

I just started getting this (running on Windows 11), after recently upgrading to Jupyter Lab 3.5.3. What worked for me was from the Jupyter Lab browser window, go to Settings | Advanced Settings Editor | Document Manager and change the "Margin for last modified timestamp check" from the default of 500 msec to 1000 msec. Haven't had the problem since.

Answer (score 0):

One of the below solutions should work

1. Shorten the name of the notebook
2. Shorten the parh from where you are accessing the notebook i.e. don't keep the notebook inside of inside of many folders, keep it on desktop
3. If you have made the copy of the notebook, make sure you are running the correct ones with correct address

Answer (score -1):

The path of The notebook file may be too long. Keep it short.

http://localhost:8888/notebooks/Desktop/...../......./....../....../....../....../your_notebook.ipynb